# How to tell which graphics card is being used in a hybrid system?

Tags: drivers, graphics, xorg, display, hybrid

How do I know which graphics card is being used in a hybrid system?

From lspci:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller [8086:0166] (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0578]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
--
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GK107 [GeForce GT 650M] [10de:0fd1] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0578]
    Kernel driver in use: nouveau
    Kernel modules: nouveau, nvidiafb
```

From Xorg.0.log:

```
[    46.292] (II) intel(0): Output VGA1 has no monitor section
[    46.340] (II) intel(0): EDID for output VGA1
[    46.388] (II) intel(0): Output VGA1 disconnected
[    46.541] (II) NOUVEAU(G0): Output VGA-2 has no monitor section
[    46.563] (II) NOUVEAU(G0): EDID for output VGA-2
[    46.563] (II) NOUVEAU(G0): Output VGA-2 disconnected
[    46.563] (II) NOUVEAU(G0): Output VGA-2 disconnected
```

Full Xorg.0.log:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/1454118/

Answer (score 0):

Optimus always use intel card to render the images (the images may be generated by nvidia card or intel card) in attached display. Maybe the HDMI port is connected to nvidia card. You have to test it. Otherwise it is always intel.

To use nvidia card you must use `bumbleebee` (+`primus` for better performance.)

Run `glxgears` to confirm, (it is not benchmark tool).

If you the fps is 50-60 then it is intel,

for nvidia you should got 600-800 in nvidia. (result are from 540m, so your card should do better )

Comment: I think you should explain glxgears a bit more to answer his question.